# How to Make Subquery's Value Change According to Parent Query's Conditions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am making a messenger app and tracking unread messages per chat room and per user. My models are like these:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255, allow_unicode=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='participants')

    def unread_messages_count(self, user):
        last_checked_message_id = Subquery(models.Message.objects.filter(
            room_listeners__receiver=user, room_listeners__room=self).values('id')[:1])
        return self.messages.filter(id__gt=last_checked_message_id).count()


class Message(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255, allow_unicode=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="messages")
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)


class RoomListener(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='room_listeners')
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='room_listeners')
    last_checked_message = models.ForeignKey(Message, default=Message.objects.first, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='room_listeners')
```

I could get a number of unread messages by writing unread_messages_count() in Room model. In addition, I want to get a number of unread messages per user. But I am confused with the way Subquery works. I want to do something like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser, RelationshipStatus):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

    def unread_messages_count
        last_checked_message_id = Subquery(models.Message.objects.filter(
            room_listeners__receiver=self).values('id'))
        return self.room_listeners.room.messages.filter(id__gt=last_checked_message_id).count()
```

But I know this is wrong... because last_checked_message_id does not change depending on parent query's status. It is a fixed value. How can I make a subquery's value change according to parent query's conditions?

Comment: I think you can use `Prefetch(..)` objects.

Comment: Sounds like you need [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#referencing-columns-from-the-outer-queryset).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you. I decided to use OuterRef.